# Username instead Email for RegisterViewModel MVC5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I want to change Email field and change for username ... So I delete default validations and create new field UserName into my RegisterViewModel

```
 public class RegisterViewModel
{
    [Required]

    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]

    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}
```

Into AccountController: I change email comparison like that:

```
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.UserName, Email = model.UserName};
            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
```

And finally in my view:

```
 <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
         <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>
```

So when I try to create user send me validation and I get this: Email 'username' is invalid.
But I delete the `[EmailAdress]` validation from RegisterViewModel, why I still get this validation?

[image]

Comment: Is `ModelState` invalid? - or do you mean you get the error when you hit the `var user = new ApplicationUser(...)` line?

Comment: I upload an Image for you can understand more easy

Comment: I think the `var user = newApplication` have an issue in logic to be more exactly in this line `Email = model.UserName` originally is `Email = model.Email`

Comment: @Stephen Muecke, I believe the image is relevant. Such validation message are displayed by ASP.Net's validation mechanism when the Model is not valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming here that you are using the default UserValidator.

The validations of your user are performed by a dedicated class. Miscrosoft's MVC5 sample provides a default implementation for those validations, but sou can override them.

In order to do so, check the `Create` method in the `ApplicationUserManager` class.

You should have something like

```
// Configure validation logic for usernames
manager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<ApplicationUser>(manager)
```

by default, this implementation will allow you to slightly customize some aspects of the user validation, such as `RequireUniqueEmail` or `AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames`. However, what you want is to completely remove the need for an e-mail in the first place.

What you will need are two things:

1. Implement a new validator
2. Register your new validator to be leveraged by your application.

#### Implement a new validator

You will need to create a new class inheriting from `UserValidator<ApplicationUser>` (`ApplicationUser` being the class used by your application to describe a user to validate).

then, you can override the `ValidateAsync` method to reflect the validations you want to perform. One cheap way here is to let the base class do all its work and add/remove the validations you want to ignore. It's not necessarily elegant though, but it will get the job done and will illustrate the purpose. You are free to implement the custom validation logic that you desire if you find it is not elegant enough.

```
var result = await base.ValidateAsync(item);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            return result;
        }

        return new IdentityResult(result.Errors.Where(s => s != string.Format("Email '{0}' is invalid.", item.UserName)));
```

#### Register your custom validator

Finally, you need to replace the current `UserValidator` by your own.

In `ApplicationUserManager.Create`, the assignation to `manager.UserValidator` by the following:

```
manager.UserValidator = new MyCustomUserValidator<ApplicationUser>(manager)
{
    RequireUniqueEmail = false
};
```

Voilà, that should do the trick.

Edit: one thing you might want to do is to remove the assignation of the Email property, because it will no longer make any sense:

```
var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.UserName, Email = model.UserName};
```

would become

```
var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.UserName };
```